# Error Duplicate Const Declaration in Switch Case Statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code and I get the error 'Duplicate Declaration query_url'.

```
  switch(condition) {
    case 'complex':
      const query_url = `something`;
      break;
    default:
      const query_url = `something`;
      break;
  }
```

I understand that query_url is getting declared twice which isn't right. But i don't know how to resolve this. Can someone please help on what should be the correct way to make this work?

Comment: Where do you need to use `query_url`?

Comment: If you need to use `query_url` outside the `switch` statement, you can't use `const`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***if you need to redeclare the same variable in each case see [@Bergi 's answer bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746467/5267669)***

if `query_url` can have multiple values depending on the switch branch obviously you need a variable ( declare either with `var` or `let` ).

const is set once and stays that way.

example usage with let

```
let query_url = '';
switch(condition) {
  case 'complex':
    query_url = `something`;
    break;
  default:
    query_url = `something`;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Simply not true. check @bergi answer.

Comment: @eltonkamami while I don't feel your answer deserves a downvote since it properly addresses the question, I do question why you would declare a variable within a switch case and expect to use it outside of that scope.

Comment: See @Bergi answer below

Comment: @eltonkamami the answer is sufficient. The question asks how to avoid duplicate definition errors, and this does that. Consider the case where the value `query_url` passed to another function. In this case, it doesn't matter that `query_url` is block-scoped because it is simply an intermediate value. You are being unreasonably harsh.

Answer (score 419):

Try wrapping the cases in blocks:

```
switch(condition) {
  case 'complex': {
    const query_url = `something`;
    … // do something
    break;
  }
  default: {
    const query_url = `something`;
    … // do something else
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Umm, won't `query_url` be confined to the block where it is defined, which sort of defeats the whole purpose of assigning to it?

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, it's only to be used in that block. I'm not sure what the actual purpose of the code is, you shouldn't use a `switch` only to select a single value - an object (or `Map`) lookup is better suited for that task.

Comment: mind blown. I considered `case` as block. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: Thank you ! This is the real solution. Because, in this trivial case, clearly you can define a global variable, but in more complex case, the global variable can be a non-sense in most of switch branches.

Comment: Interesting! My code highlighting does not even work in this case! Even they don't know it that it is possible!

Comment: In C/C++ you can't even declare variables inside a switch statement without using a block. The main inconvenience is that all editors have a different idea of how to indent braces in this case.

Comment: @SafalPillai No braces, no block :-)

Comment: @Andreyco yep. And JS isn't the only language like this. [C++ is similar](/q/92396/11107541). [and so is Java](/q/10932997/11107541)

Answer (score 17):

I personally prefer (and tend to abuse) the following in these sorts of cases:

```
const query_url = (()=> {
     switch(condition)
           case 'complex': return 'something';
           default:        return 'something-else';
})();
```

(this requires ES6 or declaring "use-strict" in Node 4.x though)

Update: Alternatively, much more compact depending on if there is any logic there or if it's a simple assignment:

```
const query_url = { complex: 'something' }[condition] || 'something-else';
```

Also, of course, depends on the amount of outside-logic embedded in those switch statements!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `{}` to scope your switch case.

**For your case**, you need to return the variable as long as the var exists and is accessible between curly braces:

```
 switch(condition) {
    case 'complex': {
      const query_url = `something`;
      return query_url;
    }
    default: {
      const query_url = `something`;
      return query_url;
    }
  }
```

**If you won't use `return`**, you must declare a `let query_url` above your switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your `switch` in a function with some return statements :

```
var condition;
function aSwitch(condition){
switch(condition) {
    case 'complex':
      return 'something';
    default:
      return 'something';
  }
}
const query_url = aSwitch(condition);
```

Comment: if you dont `"use strict";` some weird things will occur with your code. each return statement is creating/assinging to a global variable query url.

Comment: @antoniskamamis Edited. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: you just have to return the value without an assignment that will either create a global or cause an error

Answer (score 1):

```
const query_url={
  complex:'something complex',
  other:'other thing'
}[condition]
```

The drawback is,you can't have default with object,you need to have addition check of condition.